# I'd like to know the sentence structure of "Can you smell paint?"

Tags: grammar

This is from a textbook "English Grammar in Use". There is a sentence *"Can you smell paint?"*

The usage of "smell" is:

1. I smell of roses.
2. It smells nice.
3. I can smell that something is burning.

These three are what I understand so far. Then how about this sentence?  I checked "paint" in a dictionary, but it has verb and noun.  So I'd like to know the structure of this sentence.

Comment: Check a dictionary: you will find another meaning for *smell*, "perceive the odour of something".

Comment: @StoneyB I see, I didn't know about that.   I just checked the dictionary and there is a sentences like "Do you smell gas?"  Your comment solved my question already.   Thank you very much.

Comment: We can also smell **painting**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third usage of smell ( *I can smell that something is burning* ) is as a verb - it is an action, with *can* in front of it as a modal auxiliary verb.

The sentence you are asking about, *Can you smell paint?* employs the same usage of *smell.*  The subject (you) and auxiliary verb (can) are inverted because it is a question, but imagine it as a statement instead:

> You can smell paint.

Subject:  *You*

auxiliary verb: *can*

verb: *smell*

direct object: *paint*

Comment: Then, can I say like, "I can smell cigasrettes in my room,  Could you change my room."?   at the hotel?  I often see a sentence like, "My room smells of cigarettes."  Do both sentences mean the same thing?

Answer (score -2):

Turning [StoneyB's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) into an answer:

> Check a dictionary: you will find another meaning for *smell*, "perceive the odour of something".